# I don't have sbt console in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have created my first Sbt project and I would like to open Sbt console. Perhaps I make a confusion on what is Sbt plugin. I have scala plugin so I suppose Sbt is embeded inside it since I have Sbt windows.
When I look inside View -> Tool Windows I don't see Sbt console but I see Sbt

[image]
Even In Sbt panel, I don't see it
[image]
In this blog 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/03/23/scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea-2017-1-cleaner-ui-sbt-shell-repl-worksheet-akka-support-and-more/
I find at section 2:

> It’s now possible to build projects using SBT (instead of IntelliJ IDEA’s internal build system). As this option is still experimental, it should be manually enabled via Build / Execution / Deployment / Build Tools / SBT / Use SBT shell for build and import:

but I don't see Use SBT shell for build and import checkbox.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have another button near "Detach SBT project (Delete)" in the SBT menu "Start SBT shell" (see here: https://pasteboard.co/H0VTcct.png). I'm using IntelliJ IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6
Build #IC-172.4574.11. I see you have 3 errors in the event log. I would try fixing them and updating IntelliJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running IntelliJ 2016.2. The integrated sbt shell and build by shell option is only available from 2017.1. I suggest you upgrade IntelliJ and the IntelliJ Scala plugin directly to 2017.3, where the options you are looking for are available.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the sbt console from IntelliJ. For that you must run sbt in a terminal (even within IntelliJ), and once you’re inside the sbt shell type ‘console’ or ‘consoleQuick’ (runs the console without compiling the project you run it at).

Comment: Yes you can (from the embedded sbt shell), but a.moussa seems to be inquiring about the sbt shell, which isn't available in their version.